# Translate parameters in object arrays into their own type in .NET Emit

Tags: c#, cil, gac-msil

There are some definations:

```cs
public class Message
{
    public SayType Say(string name)
    {
        Console.Write("Hello," + name );
        return SayType.Name;
    }
}

public enum SayType
{
    Name
}
```

```cs
 public delegate SayType SayDelegate(Message message,params object[] o);
    public void Test()
    {
        DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = 
            new DynamicMethod("Say",typeof(SayType),new Type[]{typeof(Message),typeof(object)});
               var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg,0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg,1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4,0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof(string));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,typeof(Message).GetMethods()[0]);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        System.Delegate delegates = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(SayDelegate));
        delegates.DynamicInvoke(new Message(),"b");
}
```

The second segement of the code is designed for the Message.Say specially. Which means I know there is just one parameter in the object arrays.

What I want is to cast the first member in the object arrays as string.

However, I got a bug:

```cs
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' ca
nnot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DynamicInvoke` doesn't know that the second parameter of your delegate is a `params`, so it doesn't wrap the argument `"b"` in an `object[]`. `params` is only a C# language feature after all.

So either don't use `DynamicInvoke`:

```
((SayDelegate)delegates).Invoke(new Message(),"b");
```

Or wrap `"e"` in a `object[]` yourself.

```
delegates.DynamicInvoke(new Message(), new object[] {"b"});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also found this bug just now. And now it has more bugs and I update the post.

Comment: Sorry, the more bugs are caused by my reason. I have edit post and delete more bugs. Thank you very much.